# Nested Javascript Object : recursion and "complex" transformation (with lodash)

Tags: javascript, recursion, lodash, data-manipulation

### I apologize in advance for the complex example here; I tried to trim it down as much as I could to illustrate what I try to achieve

I have a complex structure that I need to traverse and transform based on some conditions; Here's an (short) example of the structure that should cover most scenarios:

```
{  PROP1: {
       metadata: Object,  // somewhere deeper in metadata I have a `value` key
       parent: { $ref: String },
       employee: {
           parent: { $ref: String },
           id: String,
           metadata: Object,
           products: {
              metadata: Object,
              model: { $ref: String },
              type: 'array',
              value: ["String", "String" , "String"] ,
              [...]     
           },
           model: {
               id: String,
               email: {
                   metadata: Object,
                   value: 'a@b.com',
                   type: 'string',
                   validity: Object,
                   [...]
               },
               name: {
                   firstName: {
                       metadata: Object,
                       value: 'John',
                       type: String,
                       validity: Object,
                       [...]
                   },
                   lastName: {
                       metadata: Object,
                       value: 'Smith',
                       type: String,
                       validity: Object,
                       [...]
                   },

               }
           },
           operations: {
               id: String,
               items: [
                   { action: {value: "UPDATE", model: {$ref: String }, [...] }, 
                   {...}
               ],
               metadata: Object,
               [...]
           }
       }
   },
   PROP2: {
       // similar as PROP1       
   },
   [... and so on ...]

}
```

I basically need to clean that up before sending it to the backend;

- Whenever a value contains `$ref`, I don't want the key/val pair (e.g.: PROP1.parent is of no use and can be omitted)
- whenever a value contains `value`, I need to omit everything else and move the value of `value` as the value of `key` (e.g.: PROP1.employee.products should equal ['String', 'String', 'String'])
- keys like `id`, `metadata`, `validity` (etc) can be completely omitted regardless of its content

**So the end result should be along those lines**:

```
{ PROP1: {
      employee: {
          products: ['item','item','item'],
          model: {
              email: 'a@b.com',
              name: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'},
          },
          operations: [
              {action: 'UPDATE'}
          ]
      }
  },
  PROP2: { ... }
}
```

---

I tried lots of different approaches using different `lodash` methods but couldn't wrap my head around this...

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code, try something like this. Implement the specifics and post more info when you run into trouble.

```
var ignoreKeyArray = ["id", ...] // keys to ignore and remove
var newJSON = "{}";
for (property in JSON) {
    var newProp = parseJSON(key, property);
    insert newProp in newJSON object
}

var parseJSON = function (key, jsonBlob) {
     if (key in ignoreKeyArray || jsonBlob contains value "$ref")
         return "";

     var jsonOut = key + ": {}";
     for (child in jsonBlob) {
         add parseJSON(child) to jsonOut;
     }
     return jsonOut;
}
```

If you have any questions, comment so I can extend the answer and clarify.